# what is the best performance on a range join

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a performance issue on spark sql. Which one of the cases is better?

Let's say we have a dataframe

```
tableA: 
timestamp |  id
10:00:00  |   1
10:00:00  |   2
10:00:00  |   3
10:01:00  |   1
10:01:00  |   2
10:01:00  |   3
```

and another one:

```
tableB:
timestamp_a | timestamp_b
08:00:00    | 11:00:00
09:00:00    | 12:00:00
```

I want to join these two tables with a left join on

```
timestamp > timestamp_a && timestamp < timestamp_b
```

and tableA being the left table.

I am trying to figure out if the performance:

First case is the left join I described

Second case is to left join the distinct timestamp of tableA with this left join I described and then cross join them with the distinct id column of tableA

Comment: Size of tables? distinct is often a good precursor

Comment: 700k for tableB and 150k for distinct tableA on column timestamp and  200 rows on column id

Comment: You have overlaps in the second table.  Is that really how the data is structured?

Answer (score 0):

If you have overlaps, then I think the second method will be better -- particularly if there are lots of duplicates in the first:

```
select aa.*, b.*
from (select distinct timestamp
      from tableA
     ) a left join
     tableB b
     on a.timestamp > b.timestamp_a and
        a.timestamp < b.timestamp_b left join
     tableA aa
     on aa.timestamp = a.timestamp;
```

If there are few duplicates in the first table, then this probably won't help much.

Comment: every distinct timestamp of tableA has over 200 appearances with different id. so yes. And yes tableB has a lot of overlaps.

Comment: @user3478067 . . . I mean *within* table B.  The time periods overlaps with each other.  Normally in this situation, there are 0 or 1 matches.